# Add Sass collection values together?

Tags: css, sass

I have a Sass collection containing several heights in pixels that I would like to total and use as another variable. Is this possible in Sass?

I looked into [@for, @each and @while loops](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while), but couldn't figure out how to cumulatively add the results to a variable.

```
$section-height: (640px, 621px, 504px, 804px);
$section-height-total: ???

body{
  height: $section-height-total;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$section-height` is a list, so you can use any of `@for`, `@each`, or `@while` to iterate over it in similar ways. Here's one way using `@each`:

```
$section-height: (640px, 621px, 504px, 804px);
$section-height-total: 0;

@each $height in $section-height {
  $section-height-total: $section-height-total + $height;
}

body {
  height: $section-height-total;
}
```

which outputs:

```
body {
    height: 2569px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I had it in my head that Sass variables were more like constants. That was clearly incorrect.